# Adding an environment to LyX for dividing a proof into steps

Tags: lyx, lists, lyx-layouts

My question is basically a combination of the questions [Is it possible to use the enumerate/itemize environment within the proof/remark environment in a nice way?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59573/is-it-possible-to-use-the-enumerate-itemize-environment-within-the-proof-remark) and [Create new paragraph style in LyX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/create-new-paragraph-style-in-lyx/8787#8787).

When I write a mathematical document in LyX, I frequently want to divide my proofs into steps. Up to now, I have often simply used the enumerate environment to do this.

This has the advantage that the numbering of the steps is handled automatically by LyX and that I can reference the individual steps later on using the usual Labels and References.

One of the disadvantages is that I am not really satisfied how the output looks afterwards, i.e. my "steps" are somewhat flushed to the right.

In the first question linked above, the user egreg proposed to simply use

```
\newenvironment{steps}{\setcounter{step}{0}}{}
\newcounter{step}
\newcommand{\proofstep}{\par\refstepcounter{step}Step~\thestep.\space\ignorespa‌​ces}
```

as a solution in LaTeX.

It would be really nice if I could integrate this in LyX, i.e. I would like to have environments

1. Steps
2. step

(or something like that), which result in the above LaTeX environments/commands to be used by LyX. I would also like to be able to reference the individual steps using labels and references.

The second question linked above describes how to add a new environment (the quotation environment) to LyX.

I tried to adapt this to the case of enumerate/itemize environments, but the format of these seems to be more complicated. Also, I guess I somehow have to tell LyX to use `\proofstep` instead of `\item` and I am not sure how to do this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can create your own layout (the thing that controls how LyX does something and which command it does to do it). It is just a simple text file, no C++ programming required. However, it would take some time. See Help > Customization. Also look at the examples in the lib/layouts folder.

Comment: @scottkosty: Thank you, I will try that. If I manage it, I will post my solution as an answer.