# Make `enumerate` start from a new line

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate, amsthm

I'd like to put `enumerate` on a new line, but cannot use `\newline` because there is no line to end!
Here is the code:

```
\newtheorem*{quoz}{Teoremi del quoziente}
\begin{quoz} % \newline here does not work
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Se $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} |f(x)| = +\infty$ allora $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} \frac1{f(x)} = 0$.
        \item Se $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} f(x) = 0$ allora $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} \frac1{|f(x)|} = +\infty$.
        \item Se $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} f(x) = l$ allora $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} \frac1{f(x)} = \frac1l$.
        \item Se $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} f(x) = l$ e $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} g(x) = m \neq 0$, allora $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac lm$.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{quoz}
```

Currently the problem is that the first point starts where the theorem's title is. I find it kind of ugly. Is there a way to make it start after a new line?

I tried doing

```
\begin{quoz}$ $\newline
    \begin{enumerate}
%...
```

But that adds too much space and feels like a hack. Is there a better way?

EDIT: I discovered that for some weird reason this works

```
\begin{quoz}$ $
    \begin{enumerate}
%...
```

I don't get why because `$ $` should be inline... Nevertheless, is there a better way?

Comment: Does `\leavevmode` do?

Comment: @Manuel: I get `undefined control sequence`. Is it defined in some package?

Comment: Perhaps you mistyped it.  `\leavevmode` is basic TeX (no package required).

Comment: `\leavevmode` should work. As anything that starts a paragraph like `\ `, `~`, `\mbox{}`, ...

Comment: @Manuel Yeah it works, thanks! I hadn't typed the second `v`, what a stupid mistake.

Comment: while it is possible to use `\mbox{}` etc, it is the wrong way really. You have not shown how you defined `quoz` but fro example `amsthm` if you are using that has a `break` style that puts a linebreak after the heading.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Well `quoz` is just `\newtheorem*{quoz}{Teoremi del quoziente}`

Comment: @rubik that doesn't really say anything there are several implementations of `\newtheorem`, one in latex itself and different ones in the packages `theorem`, `ntheorem`, `amsthm`  to name a few. It's always best to include a complete small document that demonstrates the problem, so peolple can adapt it in answers.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Oh I'm sorry, I didn't know that! The one that I am using is from `amsthm`.

Comment: The second and third items are mathematically wrong.

Comment: @egreg: Why? Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: @rubik I didn't see the absolute value, sorry; but you need `$l\ne0$` in the third item.

Comment: question answered here: [Is it possible to use the enumerate/itemize environment within the proof/remark environment in a nice way?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59578/579).  the ams author faq item mentioned there has even more information.

Comment: @egreg: You are absolutely right, thanks for noticing. Somehow I forgot to add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that also teaches you how not to define a new unnumbered theorem each time. The `*`-version of `genthm` does a break, in case you want to start with a list. However, I find this bad style and I'd start the theorem by stating the general assumptions we're making on the functions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem*{nonamethm}{\nonamethmname}
\newcommand{\nonamethmname}{}

\newenvironment{genthm}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\nonamethmname}{#1}\nonamethm}
 {\endnonamethm}
\newenvironment{genthm*}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\nonamethmname}{#1}\nonamethmcheck}
 {\endnonamethm}

\newcommand\nonamethmcheck[1][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \nonamethm\relax
  \else
    \nonamethm[#1]%
  \fi
  \mbox{}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{genthm*}{Teoremi del quoziente}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Se $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} |f(x)| = +\infty$,
  allora $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} \frac{1}{f(x)} = 0$.

\item Se $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} f(x) = 0$,
  allora $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} \frac1{|f(x)|} = +\infty$.

\item Se $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} f(x) = l \neq 0$,
  allora $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} \frac1{f(x)} = \frac{1}{l}$.

\item Se $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} f(x) = l$ e $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} g(x) = m \neq 0$,
  allora $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{l}{m}$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{genthm*}

\begin{genthm}{Teoremi del quoziente}
Siano $f$ e $g$ funzioni definite in un intorno bucato di~$\alpha$.
\begin{enumerate}
\item Se $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} |f(x)| = +\infty$,
  allora $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} \frac{1}{f(x)} = 0$.

\item Se $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} f(x) = 0$,
  allora $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} \frac1{|f(x)|} = +\infty$.

\item Se $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} f(x) = l \neq 0$,
  allora $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} \frac1{f(x)} = \frac{1}{l}$.

\item Se $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} f(x) = l$ e $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} g(x) = m \neq 0$,
  allora $\lim\limits_{x \to \alpha} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{l}{m}$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{genthm}

\end{document}
```

The optional argument (coming after the mandatory argument) is supported for both environments.

[image]

Comment: This is very useful, I'll do like you suggested. Thanks again!