# Enumerate formating: The number not straight?

Tags: enumerate

[image: The number not straight.]

I wana the numbering go down, with other number. Go to straight.

```
\begin{exercise} 
\begin{enumerate}
\item 123
\item 123
\item 123
\item 123
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
```

Comment: What's the code you use?

Comment: Try `\leavevmode` as in [Enumerate alignment problem in theorem environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73741/35864), [Is it possible to use the enumerate/itemize environment within the proof/remark environment in a nice way?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59573/35864) and [Theorem formatting: strange interaction with itemize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49171/35864).

Comment: Please post a [fully compilable example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001)
 rather than just a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `\hfill`, it will align the first number with the others, like this:

```
\begin{exercise}
\hfill % moves whatever comes next to a new line
\begin{enumerate}
    \item What is your name?
    \item What is your quest?
    \item What is the capital of Assyria?
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
```

Comment: `\mbox{}` would suffice